# Images not displaying in Qtenv, showing question marks instead in Omnet++

Tags: omnet++

[Qtnev environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjJA4.png)

I have used the "i=device/f1" tag to refer to the images in my .ned file. But when i run it, i get is the question marks in the Qtenv environment not the images that i wish to display. I have tried setting the exact path on the .ned file "i=omnetpp-5.6.2/images/device/f1". Still has not worked, how would i resolve this?

[i tag in .ned file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mraMM.png)

Answer (score 0):

You get question marks because Omnet++ they do not find your image in this path. In your installation directory, Omnet++ has a folder with images. In this folder, you can create your folder with your custom images or icons. For example, you can download something like [this](https://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/car-of-formula-1_55299?term=formula%201%20car&page=1&position=4&page=1&position=4&related_id=55299&origin=tag) and add it to your custom folder.

In my images, I have created a folder with the name cars, I add the above image and rename it to f1.png.

[image]

In my ned file, I add the folder and the name of the image

```
    Server: StandardHost {
        @display("p=303,254;i=cars/f1");
    }
```

Keep in mind that maybe you want to resize your photo before you add it to your folder to fit better on your screen.